# Remove part of circle using Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Can either arc between two  arbitrary points on the circumference of circle be deleted by clicking on the first and second point on circumference respectively?

Comment: It can be if you write an appropriate code for it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the centerpoint of the circle it's fairly easy.

You can draw your new arc like this using a custom Kinetic.Shape:

```
context.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle,sweepCounterclockwise)
```

Where:

- **cx,cy**: The centerX/centerY of the existing circle are the cx,cy of the new arc.
- **radius**: Use the distance formula to calculate the radius: Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy).
- **angles**: Use Math.atan2 to calculate the 2 angles of the clicks vs the circles centerpoint.
- **sweep**: Use the counterclockwise option to draw the new arc with a big or little swing.